# fields of child object disappear while marshalling

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb, marshalling

I have a parent abstract class

```
@XmlTransient
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({ ChildA.class, ChildB.class })
public class Parent {
    String fieldParent;
}
```

And 2 children of it

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "childa")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ChildA extends Parent {
    String fieldA;
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "childb")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ChildB extends Parent {
    List<OtherObject> fieldB;
}
```

Where OtherObject is another class annotated with `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlAccessorType` too
I have also written a Service which returns a list with both ChildA and ChildB

```
public class MitteilungResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/mypath")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Collection<Parent> getAllChildren() {
        Collection<Parent> collection = new ArrayList<Parent>();
        collection.add(new ChildA());
        collection.add(new ChildB());
        return collection;
    }
}
```

While debugging, the method returns the correct list with these two objects, each with its correct type. But when I call this from my client and I inspect the network messages I see that only `fieldParent` is being sent while `fieldA` and `fieldB` are vanished. There must be a problem while marshalling the list, but I cannot figure out what is happening

I have read hundred of posts about this issue and tried different alternatives but I don't find the problem. Can someone tell me what can be wrong?

**EDIT**

After some testing I came up to the following:

If I change my method `public Collection<Parent> getAllChildren() {...}` to return a single object instead of a Collection It Works! Sending a collection is never working, it doesn't matter if the collection has objects of one type or of several types. Is there any reason why a List of objects removes the attributes of child objects while a single object doesn't remove them?

Comment: What exactly are you marshalling? A `MitteilungResource` instance? Does it have any JAXB annotations?

Comment: MitteilungResource is just the name of the class where my service is implemented. The collection of parents is being marshalled and sent to the client. Then the attributes of the children disappear

Comment: Do you iterate over the collection and marshal each element as a separate XML? Or do you try to marshal the collection as a whole?

Comment: @G_H I have the method annotated with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` so that jaxb marshals it automatically